# Localhost install: Administrator lost administrator access; cannot access Dashboard

Tags: wp-admin, admin, dashboard, user-access

I have been building a WordPress-based website in my localhost (‘localhost/dzup_online/wordpress’) for a week now and I have been accessing the Dashboard several times now without fail. (Theme: Twentysixteen (default))

I installed another WordPress site for checking out other themes (‘localhost/dzup_online_4/wordpress’). (Theme: Clean Journal Child theme (user-made))

Since working on the ‘dzup_online_4’ website, I decided to make it my main website so I switched the names of their root directories (‘dzup_online’ <- -> ‘dzup_online_4’)

Of course, my website broke so I had to update wp-config.php to change ‘DB_NAME’, ‘DB_USER’ and $table_prefix (‘wp_’ -> ‘dzup_wp’) to point to the other database and database user. (The passwords for both database users are the same) (I also did the same for the other website) I also added the correct privileges for the database for each database user.

I updated ‘dzup_wp_options’ in the database for the ‘option_name’s ‘siteurl’ and ‘home’ to reflect the new root folder name for the website.

I renamed the database tables to be prefixed with the name $table_prefix (‘dzup_wp_’).

I also replaced the ‘guid’s of the posts in ‘dzup_wp_posts’ with the new root folder name.

At this point, I can access my home page quite fine and can access my Dashboard as an administrator.

I tried switching pages and found out that I had to modify my .htaccess too. This is the new content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dzup_online/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dzup_online/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I refreshed the page and suddenly, I do not see the Dashboard menu button in the Admin Bar anymore.

I reverted back to my old .htaccess but my administrator account seems to have still lost administrator rights.

I tried adding a new user through this [tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/) but the newly added user still cannot access the Dashboard.

I renamed the ‘meta_key’s in ‘dzup_wp_usermeta’ table to have the new table prefix at the start with the following values:

dzup_wp_capabilities a:1:{s:13:”administrator”;b:1;}
dzup_wp_user_level 10

For both user accounts, I still do not have administrator rights.

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case, did you change siteurl and home entries in the dzup_options table via phpmyadmin ?

Comment: @Benoti Hi! Yes, I did do the change through phpmyadmin

Comment: I didn't notice that you modifiied option entry `wp_user_roles` to `dzup_wp_user_roles` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{$table_prefix}user_roles` entry in the options table must begin with the actual table prefix.

Your website was with a prefix of `wp_` so the entry was called `wp_user_roles`. When modifying the table prefix you need to change it with the new one:

```
dzup_wp_user_roles
```

Hope it works !

Comment: Whew... thanks @Benoti! I can now access my Dashboard on both local sites.

Comment: That's cool ! Don't forget to mark the question as resolved ;-)

Comment: Sorry didn't know how to before :D